# Javascript syntax - declaring object

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes

I'm new to this. Can someone please help explain this syntax to me?

```
routes = {
  "GET" : {
    "/info": (req,res) => {
        res.writeHead(httpStatus.OK, {"Content-Type": "text/html"})
        res.end("Welcome to the Info page")
      }
  },
    "POST" : {}
};
```

Later routes object is called in this statement

```
  if (routes[req.method][req.url]) {
      routes[req.method][req.url](req,res);
```

It looks like the route object has a key and value pair, then the value has another key and value pair? and what is the if statement checking  "if (routes[req.method][req.url])"?

Comment: routes[req.method][req.url] checks to see if in the GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, etc objects the path exists so if I were to call routes["GET"]["/info"] that would return true.

Answer (score 0):

Routes is an *`object`*, where in you have a route for specific http methods.
For instance, `routes["GET"]["/info"]` has the value of an es6 *arrow function* that takes two arguments: `req, res`.

> Later routes object is called in this statement

Your code is checking if the property for the request *method* and request *url* exist in the `routes` object, say if somebody requested `/info` with the `GET` method, then the callback function `routes["GET"]["/info"]` would be called with the arguments `req` and `res`, which are your route parameters.

Comment: I have another example that confuses me 

const routeResponseMap = {
"/info": "<h1>Info Page</h1>",
"/contact" : "<h1>Contact Us</h1>",

};

if (routeResponseMap[req.url]){

    res.writeHead(httpStatus.OK, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
   
  res.end(routeResponseMap[req.url]);
}

It looks like if someone enters "info", routeResponseMap[req.url] in the if statement will have the value "info" but the res.end(routeResponseMap[req.ur]) returns the html  <h1> not the info when I run it. 
In my original question, if I do res.end(routes["Get"]), will it return "/info"?

Comment: @monkeycoder the question not clear. If this answer makes you clear, please mark it correct. Post the second one in a new question instead. This is irrelevant to the current context.